# Youtube Data API v3 403 error: Exceeded quota with one single request made

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api

I am getting the following 403 by making very few, or even a single request with the Youtube Data API v3 key:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
        "domain": "youtube.quota",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My key is restricted for the Youtube API only and I am using it locally in a React.js app. Tried to use a new key, same issue. Looking at the daily quota accepted, this should be 10000 units, I am guessing an approx 300 requests or thereabout, so I am not getting it why I keep getting the 403 there. I am making the API calls as such in my React app, using the videoURL in a simple iframe:

```
const fetchYoutube = async () => {
        if (selectedCountry) {
            const ytURL = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${YT_API_KEY}&channelId=${channelID}&part=snippet,id&order=relevance&maxResults=10&q=Geography+Now!+${selectedCountry.name}`;

            const result = await Axios(ytURL);

            if (result.data.items[0]) {
                setVideoURL(`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${result.data.items[0].id.videoId}`);
            } else {
                setVideoURL(null);
            };
        };
    };
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, and many thanks in advance!